# How to log camera video to Rasberry Pi?

Tags: sd-card, video

I have a Raspberry Pi and a webcam, what I want is to connect the webcam to the Pi, and log the camera content to an SD card. How to do it? I have searched it on google, it seems I need a video card to do it?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You do need a video capture card to 'freeze' one frame of video, or capture 'n' number of frames to send to the SD card. Remember video is dynamic and to dump it into your SD card in real time would heat up the CPU and quickly fill up your SD card. If you are going to do this set up a partition in the SD card just for video.

Comment: [Just use Motion.](https://motion-project.github.io/)  Will work just fine with a webcam and a Raspberry Pi.  Timed recording, motion detection.  All you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not need a video card.  If you have the Raspberry Pi camera you have many options.  [RPi-Cam-Web-Interface](https://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface) being one of the more popular options.

If you use a USB webcam, you still have many options.  [VLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player) would be a good place to start.

Edit:  As JRE mentioned in a comment, [motion](https://motion-project.github.io/) is a very easy to use app to do this.